# how to use updated hook in typegoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

I added a `pre` hook on `updateOne` events, but it works different from `save` events...

I assume this is because the update command usually passes a matcher as it's first argument.
I did try to catch the *second* argument but its an anonymous func i'm not sure how to use.

Mongoose docs talk about this, but I'm not sure how to actually modify the Mongoose schema directly from Typegoose.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

> Note: Unlike schema.pre('remove'), Mongoose registers updateOne and deleteOne middleware on Query#updateOne() and Query#deleteOne() by default. This means that both doc.updateOne() and Model.updateOne() trigger updateOne hooks, but this refers to a query, not a document. To register updateOne or deleteOne middleware as document middleware, use schema.pre('updateOne', { document: true, query: false }).

```
// this does NOT work
@pre<Question>('updateOne', function (opts) {
  debug.log('updating', this)
  debug.log('opts', opts)
  recalcVotes(this) // incompatible type
})

// this does work
@pre<Question>('save', function () {
  this.cname = this.cname || makeCname(this.text)
  this.simple = this.simple || makeCname(this.text)
  // mutates because we can't modify 'this = ..'
  recalcVotes(this)
  debug.log('cleaned', this)
})
```

```
Argument of type 'Query<Question>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Question'.
  Type 'Query<Question>' is missing the following properties from type 'Question': text, tag, _id
```

EDIT:  I just updated to the latest package versions
No longer gives an error, but the types are different.

```
-    "mongoose": "^5.10.15",
+    "mongoose": "^5.11.0",
```

and intellisense detects different types for this pre `updateOne` vs `save` hooks

pre.updateOne = `any`

[image]

pre.save = `this: DocumentType<Question>`

[image]

```
npm ls mongoose
bot@1.0.0 /Users/dc/dev/ten/puzzleparty/server
└── mongoose@5.11.0

npm ls @typegoose/typegoose
bot@1.0.0 /Users/dc/dev/ten/puzzleparty/server
└── @typegoose/typegoose@7.4.2

npm -v
6.14.9
node -v
v14.5.0
npx tsc -v
Version 4.1.2
```

Comment: what version of typegoose & mongoose and @types/mongoose are used?

Comment: I bumped to latest and checked again

Comment: could you update to typegoose 7.4.4 (and mongoose to 5.10.18, highest supported by typegoose at the moment) and report back?

Comment: It's a mess, you have to use both.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's complaining because you're trying to return a document, while it's just a query